# Android Activity Layout with Multiple Fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I'm new to Android, there's so much unknown that I don't even know which direction to look for solutions.. I hope experienced developers can enlighten me on this..

I have a UI design that is quite different from common Android app layout, most of which I've seen so far use Tabs or the upper-left corner control button..

My Main Activity is 1) full-screen without ActionBar 2) has a fixed "control panel" layer occupying the bottom half of the screen 3) a full-screen ViewPager (contains three pages, can swipe left and right) below the "control panel" layer.

I'm able to achieve either 1&2 or 1&3 but not all together. I think the main problem is to add the control panel on top of the ViewPager within the same screen.

I tried to put ViewPager and "control panel" as two fragments inside the MainActivity layout.. it didn't work... below is the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:id="@+id/container"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              tools:context="com.example.MainActivity">

    <fragment
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_pager"/>

    <fragment android:name="com.example.MainFragment"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="200dip"
              android:layout_gravity="bottom"
              tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

In case you need more info, attach my MainActivity as well

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    static final int NUM_ITEMS = 3;

    private FragmentPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ViewPager mPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.hide();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAdapter = new DashboardAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mPager.setCurrentItem(1);
    }

    public static class DashboardAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public DashboardAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_ITEMS;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new FirstFragment();
                case 1:
                    return new SecondFragment();
                case 2:
                    return new ThirdFragment();
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I got Error inflating class fragment, so probably happens when I create the fragment

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment, container, false);
```

Because "control panel" is outside the ViewPager, thus the view cannot be inflated... Then what's the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `RelativeLayout` as the root of your `MainActivity`.

The `ViewPager` should be the first child with `match_parent`.
Your control panel can be aligned at the bottom using `layout_alignParentBottom="true"`. This will also make it on top of the `ViewPager`.